# jquery get how many 'div' in each after 'h3' tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

i would like to know how many `div` that are in siblings with `h3` tag located inside a parent `div` with the class `content-block-infos-events`

if some of the amount got less than 6 items, i would like to create divs tags so i can always reach to 6 items after each `h3`

for example :

```
<div class="content-block-infos-events" >
  <h3>H3 val</h3>
  <div class="views-row rows>
    TEXT 1
  </div>
  <div class="views-row rows>
    TEXT 2
  </div>
  // i have to add 4 another <div class="views-row rows>


  <h3>H3 val</h3>
  <div class="views-row rows>
    TEXT 1
  </div>
  <div class="views-row rows>
    TEXT 2
  </div>
  <div class="views-row rows>
    TEXT 3
  </div>
  <div class="views-row rows>
    TEXT 4
  </div>
  <div class="views-row rows>
    TEXT 5
  </div>
  <div class="views-row rows>
    TEXT 6
  </div>
  // no need to add the div because i have 6 divs
</div>
```

here you can find the html code : http://jsfiddle.net/Axdh6/2/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You're already getting those numbers

Comment: @Itay He wants to add `6 - i` missing `<div>`s in each group as far as I can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of selecting siblings `div` elements which is not helpful in this case, you should iterate through the `h3` elements and select their next siblings elements until the next `h3` element.

```
$('.content-block-infos-events h3').each(function() {
    var $divs = $(this).nextUntil('h3'),
        div_count = $divs.length;
    if (div_count < 6) {
        var divs = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < (6 - div_count); i++) {
            divs += "<div class='views-row rows'>added-text</div>";
        }
        $divs.last().after(divs);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6s88v/

Comment: awesome (y) , tnk u so much